# Intersect all possible combinations of list elements

Tags: r, list, combinations, intersect, combn

I have a list of vectors:

```
> l <- list(A=c("one", "two", "three", "four"), B=c("one", "two"), C=c("two", "four", "five", "six"), D=c("six", "seven"))

> l
$A
[1] "one"   "two"   "three" "four"

$B
[1] "one" "two"

$C
[1] "two"  "four" "five" "six"

$D
[1] "six"   "seven"
```

I would like to **calculate the length of the overlap between all possible pairwise combinations of the list elements**, i.e. (the format of the result doesn't matter):

```
AintB 2
AintC 2
AintD 0
BintC 1
BintD 0
CintD 1
```

---

I know `combn(x, 2)` can be used to get a matrix of all possible pairwise combinations in a vector and that `length(intersect(a, b))` would give me the length of the overlap of two vectors, but I can't think of a way to put the two things together.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`combn` works with list structures as well, you just need a little `unlist`'ing of the result to use `intersect`...

```
# Get the combinations of names of list elements
nms <- combn( names(l) , 2 , FUN = paste0 , collapse = "" , simplify = FALSE )

# Make the combinations of list elements
ll <- combn( l , 2 , simplify = FALSE )

# Intersect the list elements
out <- lapply( ll , function(x) length( intersect( x[[1]] , x[[2]] ) ) )

# Output with names
setNames( out , nms )
#$AB
#[1] 2

#$AC
#[1] 2

#$AD
#[1] 0

#$BC
#[1] 1

#$BD
#[1] 0

#$CD
#[1] 1
```

Comment: how do i get what are the elements common or intersect to any set. Here as you explained and showed it shows the total no of elements which are common to any intersection

Answer (score 25):

If I understand correctly, you can look at `crossprod` and `stack`:

```
crossprod(table(stack(l)))
#    ind
# ind A B C D
#   A 4 2 2 0
#   B 2 2 1 0
#   C 2 1 4 1
#   D 0 0 1 2
```

---

You can extend the idea if you want a `data.frame` of just the relevant values as follows:

1. Write a spiffy function

   ```
   listIntersect <- function(inList) {
     X <- crossprod(table(stack(inList)))
     X[lower.tri(X)] <- NA
     diag(X) <- NA
     out <- na.omit(data.frame(as.table(X)))
     out[order(out$ind), ]
   }
   ```
2. Apply it

   ```
   listIntersect(l)
   #    ind ind.1 Freq
   # 5    A     B    2
   # 9    A     C    2
   # 13   A     D    0
   # 10   B     C    1
   # 14   B     D    0
   # 15   C     D    1
   ```

---

Performance seems pretty decent.

Expand the `list`:

```
L <- unlist(replicate(100, l, FALSE), recursive=FALSE)
names(L) <- make.unique(names(L))
```

Set up some functions to test:

```
fun1 <- function(l) listIntersect(l)
fun2 <- function(l) apply( combn( l , 2 ) , 2 , function(x) length( intersect( unlist( x[1]) , unlist(x[2]) ) ) )
fun3 <- function(l) {
  m1 <- combn(names(l),2)
  val <- sapply(split(m1, col(m1)),function(x) {x1 <- l[[x[1]]]; x2 <- l[[x[2]]]; length(intersect(x1, x2))})
  Ind <- apply(m1,2,paste,collapse="int")
  data.frame(Ind, val, stringsAsFactors=F) 
}
```

Check out the timings:

```
system.time(F1 <- fun1(L))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.33    0.00    0.33
system.time(F2 <- fun2(L))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    4.32    0.00    4.31 
system.time(F3 <- fun3(L))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.33    0.00    6.33
```

Everyone seems to be sorting the result differently, but the numbers match:

```
table(F1$Freq)
# 
#     0     1     2     4 
# 20000 20000 29900  9900 
table(F2)
# F2
#     0     1     2     4 
# 20000 20000 29900  9900 
table(F3$val)
# 
#     0     1     2     4 
# 20000 20000 29900  9900
```

Comment: Note to readers: `stack` needs names if you're trying to use it with `list`s.

Comment: This is a very efficient solution!

Comment: This is so elegant!!

Comment: this is great saved me a ton of looping doing intersections!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
m1 <- combn(names(l),2)
val <- sapply(split(m1, col(m1)),function(x) {x1 <- l[[x[1]]]; x2 <- l[[x[2]]]; length(intersect(x1, x2))})
Ind <- apply(m1,2,paste,collapse="int")
data.frame(Ind, val, stringsAsFactors=F)   
#      Ind val
# 1 AntB   2
# 2 AntC   2
# 3 AntD   0
# 4 BntC   1
# 5 BntD   0
# 6 CntD   1
```